# Find all elements ID starting with or Ending with using JQuery in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am trying to search all input elements that starts with a partcular set of characters such as 'idAcc' where my VF page has two inputfields with id = idAccFN and id= idAccLN respectively.

```
 <apex:inputField id="idAccFN" value="{!cr.FirstName__c}" />
 <apex:inputField id="idAccLN" value="{!cr.LastName__c}" />
```

I'm using the below JQuery syntax but thats working partially ... Explained in comments below .. Kindly help.

```
 var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
 j$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( 'input[id$=Name]' ).val('Foo');  // ID ending with Name working 
    jQuery( 'input[id^=idAcc]' ).val('Apu')  //Id starting with idAcc not working 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Id you set gets prepended by VF, so you need to do a "contains" selector.  And if you want each element on the page, you need to use a ".each", like this:

```
j$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( 'input[id*=Name]' ).each(function(el){
  el.val('Foo'); // do something with the input here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason..This serves my purpose. wondering in JQuery site contains selector is represented with '~' status. Now, got the * working instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the elements on the page you will notice that the id's are actually prepended by VF with j_id0 etc (`j_id0:j_id1:page:messageDetail`)if you do not place IDs on all parent elements in your vf page. Thus the ID's do not start with the `idAcc` that you expect.

If you need the 'Starts With' then you could look at `$Component` in javascript:

> Use the $Component global variable to simplify referencing the DOM ID
>   that is generated for a Visualforce component, and reduce some of the
>   dependency on the overall page structure.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm

Comment: Thanks but somehwhere I got this syntax $('[id$=theAccFN]') working instead of using $Component. S, was assuming if there is someting that can get rid of using the $Component hierarchies.

Comment: The only way an input field would start with the ID is if you used <input> instead of the VF tags. Or you could use "contains" selector but that presents its own problems.